# How can I convert a varchar input variable "1,2,3" to a SET(1,2,3) in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

let me tell you that I created this stored procedure to generate the pivot of a table in Mysql.

It works fine, only the input variable `_cmp_id` I pass as varchar '1,2,3', when I do the comparison on and `ccc.cmp_id in (_cmp_id)` it passes as `ccc.cmp_id in ('1, 2,3')` (it only does the search for the first element, the rest is ignored). I haven't found it to pass as `ccc.cmp_id in (1,2,3)`.

Here I leave the stored procedure, which returns a varchar with the conditions to perform the pivot.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS PIVOTE;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE PIVOTE
(
    IN _cmp_status varchar(30),
    IN _cmp_id varchar (30),
    IN _adm varchar(30),
    IN _d_start varchar(30),
    IN _d_end varchar(30),
    OUT _var_out varchar(20000)
)

BEGIN
    
    SET @sql= '';
    
    SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
            'MAX(CASE WHEN ct_agents_answers_form.questions_id = ',
              ct_questions.question_id,
              ' THEN IFNULL(answer_text,answer_text) ELSE NULL END) AS pregunta'
        )
      SEPARATOR ', ') INTO @sql
    FROM camp_cdr
    left join ct_call_campaign ccc ON ccc.cmp_id = camp_cdr.camp_name
    left join admin_master am ON am.adm_id = camp_cdr.agent_id
    inner join ct_form f ON f.form_id = (SELECT form_id FROM ct_agents_answers_form where call_id = camp_cdr.call_id limit 1)
    inner join ct_agents_answers_form ON ct_agents_answers_form.call_id = camp_cdr.call_id
    inner join ct_questions ON ct_questions.question_id = ct_agents_answers_form.questions_id
    left join ct_answers ON ct_answers.answer_id = ct_agents_answers_form.answer_id
    where ccc.cmp_status = _cmp_status
    and ccc.cmp_id in (_cmp_id)
    and am.adm_is_admin = _adm
    and start_time between _d_start and _d_end;

    SET _var_out = @sql;
    
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

The procedure call is like this:

```
SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
SET @sql='';
SET @date_start = '2022-02-13';
SET @date_end = '2022-02-14';
SET @cmp_id = '1'; -- With '1' it brings me the expected result with '1,2' it only brings me the result as if it were passed '1'
SET @adm = 'agent';
SET @cmp_status = 'Active';

CALL PIVOTE(@date_start,@date_end,@cmp_id,@adm,@cmp_status,@sql);

SELECT @sql;
```

If there is a way to do this, I would appreciate your comment.

Comment: Mysql does not have an array data type, so you can only do it with a prepared statement, like the one you are creating with your stored proc.

Comment: *How can I convert a varchar input variable "1,2,3" to a SET(1,2,3) in Mysql?* #1) Use dynamic SQL (prepared statement). Complex but fast. #2) Use FIND_IN_SET() function. Simple but slow.